# Repeat column in dataframe, but replacing white spaces by a given quantity of zeros

Tags: r

I have a dataframe (df) with several columns. Column A contains values with the format "1   34", "368    879",... So with white spaces in between. 
I would like to create a new column which replaces the white spaces by a fix quantity of 0. I mean:

```
      A     Rep     New_A
1     15    3       100015  
378   567   2       37800567
45    2     4       4500002
```

For a single value, for example df[1,"A"], something like this works:

```
New_A <- gsub("[[:punct:]])|\\s+",paste(rep(0,df[1,"Rep"]), sep="", collapse=""), df[1,"A"])
```

But for the whole dataframe, I tried that, but it doesn't work:

```
df$New_A <- gsub("[[:punct:]])|\\s+",paste(rep(0,df$Rep), sep="", collapse=""), df$A])
```

I could do it with a for-loop, but I would prefer to avoid this because my dataframe has more than 1000000 rows... so it's not efficient at all...

Comment: have a look at function `mapply` (like `mapply(function(x,y){sub("\\s+", rep(0, y), x)}, x=df$A, y=df$Rep)`)

Comment: @CathG Thanks, I got it following your idea of using 'mapply'. I'll post the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the idea of @CathG, here's how I got what I was asking for:

```
df$New_A <- mapply(function(x,y){gsub("[[:punct:]])|\\s+",paste(rep(0,y), sep="", collapse=""), x)}, x=df$A, y=df$Rep)
```

where:

```
rep(0,y) #produces as much 0 as indicated in df$Rep --> gives a vector of 0

paste(rep(0,y), sep="", collapse="") #puts all zeros of the vector together (like "000")

gsub("[[:punct:]])|\\s+",...,...) #substitutes the white spaces of df$A by the "string of zeros"
```